# $3+33+\dots+33\ldots3={10^{n+1}-9^n-10\over 27}$

Tags: induction

I need help to show by Induction

$3+33+\dots+33\ldots3={10^{n+1}-9^n-10\over 27}$
Thank you.

Comment: What are you having trouble with exactly?

Comment: if $n=2$ the RHS is $101/3$  which is not an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem has a typo.

It should be $$f(n):3+33+\cdots+\underbrace{33\cdots 33}_{n \text{ digits}}=\frac{10^{n+1}-9n-10}{27}$$

Let $f(n)$ holds true for $n=m$

$$3+33+\cdots+\underbrace{33\cdots 33}_{m \text{ digits}}=\frac{10^{m+1}-9m-10}{27}$$

$$\implies 3+33+\cdots+\underbrace{33\cdots 33}_{m+1\text{ digits}}=\frac{10^{m+1}-9m-10}{27}+\underbrace{33\cdots 33}_{m+1\text{ digits}}$$
$$=\frac{10^{m+1}-9m-10}{27}+\frac{10^{m+1}-1}3$$
$$=\frac{10^{m+1}-9m-10+9(10^{m+1}-1)}{27}$$
$$=\frac{10^{m+1}(1+9)-9m-19}{27}$$

$$=\frac{10^{m+2}-9(m+1)-10}{27}$$

So, $f(n+1)$ holds true for $n=m+1$ if $f(n)$ holds true for $n=m$

Establish the base case $n=1$